# Having trouble generating arbitrary json with Haskell's Aeson package

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm a Haskell newb, having only just finished reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). I am reading [this Aeson tutorial](https://artyom.me/aeson), but I'm having trouble executing most of the code examples. For instance, I have the following in Scratch01.hs ...

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Scratch01 where

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Exts

val :: Value
val = Object $ fromList [
  ("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, Number 3]),
  ("boolean", Bool True) ]
```

... and I'm trying to execute it like this

```
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3
$ ghci -XOverloadedStrings
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :load Scratch01.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Scratch01        ( Scratch01.hs, interpreted )

Scratch01.hs:10:3:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Item Object’
                with actual type ‘(t0, Value)’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    In the expression:
      ("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, Number 3])
    In the first argument of ‘fromList’, namely
      ‘[("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, ....]),
        ("boolean", Bool True)]’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘fromList
         [("numbers", Array $ fromList [Number 1, Number 2, ....]),
          ("boolean", Bool True)]’

Scratch01.hs:10:33:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Item Array’ with actual type ‘Value’
    In the expression: Number 1
    In the first argument of ‘fromList’, namely
      ‘[Number 1, Number 2, Number 3]’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

I've been tinkering with the types for a bit, but I'm stumped. Am I using the wrong version of GHC or something?

#### Edit

I did what artyom suggested. This works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Scratch01 where

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as HM
import qualified Data.Vector as V

val :: Value
val = Object $ HM.fromList [
  ("numbers", Array $ V.fromList [Number 1, Number 2, Number 3]),
  ("boolean", Bool True) ]
```

Comment: What's your version of vector? (You can determine it by doing `cabal info vector | grep installed`.) If it's lower than 0.10.12.0, I guess that's the problem (in which case you'll have to replace `fromList` with `Vector.fromList` and `HashMap.fromList` respectively).

Comment: That works! I've edited the post with the updates.

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed if you found a solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it, rather than just update the post. That way this doesn't linger as an unanswered question...